# Is there an official Docker image with Nginx Ubuntu, Kestral, .net core 3.1, and automatic updates rolled into one?

Tags: asp.net, docker, nginx

Rather than host a .net core 3.1 MVC site with windows I'd prefer to use NGINX as a reverse proxy for Kestral on Ubuntu. A docker container that also has automatic updates installed would be ideal (automatic updates for ubuntu, nginx, AND kestral/.net core 3.1 runtime).

My understanding is this is a common setup for net core 3.1. I can find an nginx container on dockerhub. An asp.net core container. An ubuntu container. Problem is I can't seem to find a docker container that includes all the above. Is there a supported image by someone or do I have to manually create the container using some other container as the base?

Answer (score 2):

Containers are not VMs, and everything you're asking for runs counter to the container ethos.

- One service, one container.
- Containers should also be immutable and disposable. as in: you do not run software updates in the container, you update the image, start a new container, and turf the old one.
- The underlying OS image that is largely irrelevant unless you're building an image from scratch, you provide the config for the service and the image runs with that.

In short: you're not likely to find a container that includes all of that, and if you build one yourself you're going to have some serious issues trying to manage it.

What you probably *should* wind up with is a set of:

- One or more Kestral containers running your .Net app.
- An Nginx container fronting the Kestral containers.

It helps to consider that container images are composed of layers, each building on the previous. If you build containers A and B on top of the same base image you get all the benefits of only having to keep around one copy of that base, and only the differences in A and B.

If, for example, you go and build base > web server > app server > other changes and then decide that you need to update or change the "web server" layers, then you also need to completely rebuild and redeploy everything that was on top of that, even if it's all exactly the same.

Comment: Answered my question -- along with a lot of related questions with that reply. Thanks.